# Cookie not displaying on second page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a cookie so that after you click a save button, leave the page and then come back to the page, the value of the cookie should be displayed in a label at the top of the page welcoming the user back to the page.
Here is the code I am using.

```
<%@ page language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">

String welcomeBackName;
void Page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

  if (Page.IsPostBack==true)
  {
    HttpCookie RUcookie = new HttpCookie("RUcookie");
    lblMessage.Text = txtfirstname.Text.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + txtlastname.Text.ToLower() + "@radford.edu";
    RUcookie.Value = "Welcome " +txtfirstname.Text +" "+ txtlastname.Text;
    RUcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(RUcookie); 

    if(RUcookie != null)
    {
        welcomeBackName = Request.Cookies["RUcookie"].Value;
        welcomeBack.Text = welcomeBackName;
    }
  } 

}

</script>

<html>
<form id=form1 runat="server">
    <br>
    <ASP:Label id="welcomeBack" Text="" size="60" runat="server"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    First Name: <asp:TextBox id="txtfirstname" size="20" runat="server"/><br>
    <br>
    Last Name : <asp:TextBox id="txtlastname" size="20" runat="server"/><br>
    <br>
    <ASP:Button id="butSave" Text="Save" Autopostback=true runat="server"/>
    <br>

    <br>
    Email: <asp:Label id="lblMessage" size="80" forecolor=Blue runat="server"/><br>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things wrong.

You said you want this to happen when the user leaves the page and comes back. By definition, you won't be in a postback. That'd be a fresh load of the page. Instead of checking if it's a postback, you should simply check to see if the cookie exists.

The other thing is that IsPostBack is by definition, a boolean. You don't need to check if it's equivalent to true. It's either true or false.

Comment: Thanks you so much @mason I can't believe I missed that if statement being inside the postBack statement.